# Can't get bind_param() working correctly

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-insert, bindparam

I'm trying to do a simple insert on my database after retrieving a value from it, I'm following the same procedure to retrieve a value from my database as to insert values in it, but I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean
```

Here's my code:

```
    $getuid = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ?");
    $getuid->bind_param("s", $email);
    $getuid->execute();
    $getuid->bind_result($uid);
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $codpost = $_POST['codpost'];
    $municipio = $_POST['municipio'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    while($getuid->fetch()){
        echo("INSERT INTO infoclientes VALUES ($uid, $nombre, $direccion, $codpost, $municipio, $estado)");
        $infocte = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO infoclientes VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $infocte->bind_param("ssssss", $uid, $nombre, $direccion, $codpost, $municipio, $estado);
        $infocte->execute();
        $infocte->close();
    }
    $getuid->close();
```

Apparently, the error comes out from

```
$infocte->bind_param("ssssss", $uid, $nombre, $direccion, $codpost, $municipio, $estado);
```

This is the output from the echo before the second bind_param:

```
INSERT INTO infoclientes VALUES (1, Fernando Cervantes, Av. Pie de la cuesta 2, 76158, Querétaro, Querétaro)
```

Comment: How do you know the error is coming from the 2nd bind_param line and not the first one?

Comment: Before the 2nd bind_param line, theres an echo() for debugging purposes. The variable $uid is retrieved correctly by $getuid, shown by the echo output.

Comment: Free the previous resultset.  Let me know what happens then.  Prepare just once, don't loop the prepare.

Comment: Your prepare line is setting $infocte to false.  Place an error check on your prepare line and add the response to your question.  Please also include your table structure.

Comment: Shouldn't your bind_param types be "ississ" ?

Comment: How was the table created? Can you do a "show create table infoclientes" in your mysql client?

Comment: I agree with @mickmackusa, the prepare should be out of the loop, bind_param and execute for every record to insert. Also true that data type should be at least 'isssss' but should not break it.

Comment: One more thing, You are calling 2 Query on the same mysqli object (connection). Not sure you can do that without using multi_query(). I'm saying not sure because you're preparing 2 statement from the same connection and that might be a differente thing.

Comment: do var_dump($infocte), i bet it's boolean false because $mysqli->prepare() failed.

Comment: @FerCervantes  If you don't present some error checking information on this question soon, I have a feeling that YourCommonSense will come through and stamp it with a "I don't know how to check for mysqli errors" duplicate question closure.

Comment: @kojow7 Here's the output

`CREATE TABLE `infoclientes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `cp` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `municipio` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `infoclientes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `members` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

Comment: Guys, I got it to work! I just moved $getuid->close() to the line before the echo(). I guess it was as @LouisLoudogTrottier mentioned, I was trying to prepare both queries while the same connection was opened.

Comment: Glad we learned something. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work! I just moved $getuid->close() to the line before the echo(). I guess it was as @LouisLoudogTrottier mentioned, I was trying to prepare both queries while the same connection was opened.